# Youtube Offline Video Upload using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, youtube, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to upload a youtube video (short), on user's behalf.

Authentication is happening in a web application that stores the token/refresh token in a database. A script is used then to upload the video, pulling credentials from the database.

Since there is no comprehensive documentation for the nodejs googleapis library, I'm asking for some guidance here.

```
let tokens = {
                    access_token:data.youtube_token,
                    refresh_token:data.youtube_refresh_token
    }

    const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
                'my-credentials',
                'my-credentials',
                'https://myapp.com/api/google/oauth2callback'   
    );

    oauth2Client.credentials = data.youtube_token 

    const service = google.youtube('v3')

    let title = 'Testing #Shorts'       
    let description = 'Testing description #Shorts'     
    let tags = '#short'     
    
    let videoFilePath = 'link-to-video'     
    const downloadStream = got.stream(videoFilePath);

    service.videos.insert({
                    auth: oauth2Client.credentials,
                    part: 'snippet,status',
                    requestBody: {
                        snippet: {
                            title,
                            description,
                            defaultLanguage: 'en',
                            defaultAudioLanguage: 'en'
                        },
                        status: {
                            privacyStatus: "private"
                        },
                    },
                    media: {
                        body: downloadStream,
                    },
                }, function(err, response) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log(response.data)

                    console.log('Video uploaded. Uploading the thumbnail now.')
                                /*
                    service.thumbnails.set({
                        auth: auth,
                        videoId: response.data.id,
                        media: {
                            body: fs.createReadStream(thumbFilePath)
                        },
                    }, function(err, response) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
                            return;
                        }
                        console.log(response.data)
                    })
                    */
                });
```

Comment: what is the issue with what you have now?

Comment: Well, the issue is that I found this code on the web and since there's no API reference to look at, I have no clue why it's not working. It's currently throwing a 400. I should've included that info in the description.

Comment: What i would sugest is you have a look at the [google drive node.js quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/nodejs) that will show you how authorization works.   Then check out the upload example [upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#node.js)  That will show you how to patch together upload.

Comment: And if you cant get that to work and your very desperate.   I will have a look.

Comment: I think I got the authorization part done, the user logs in using their google account in the settings page, then I save those credentials to the database. The issue most likely is with the way I'm appending the authentication credentials (token) to the library function.